# struggling to check whether file elements on a specific line is single integer or not.Any pointers will be helpful

Tags: python

Write a program using Python 3.x 
Write the scipt that will read "input.txt" and print the first 5 lines of the file input.txt that consists of the single odd number to stdout The file may contain lines having numeric and non numeric data your script should ignore all the lines that contain anything except single odd integer

Assumption:"input.txt" is present in the same folder where script resides

My code is as follows

```
f = open('input.txt', mode='r')
t = f.readlines()
print(t)
lst1 = []
for i in t:
    try:
        if int(i):
            lst1.append(i)
    except ValueError:
        print ("{}is not a valid number,ignoring the same".format(i))
print ("This is a list with numeric values", lst1)
for i in lst1:
    if int(i) % 2 == 1:
        print("Odd numbers are: ", i)

Input.txt :
123a
13aa
a1
1s2
2
3
3
455
56
6
7
8
```

output :

```
yogi@fdfd:~/Python-Practice$python3 test.py 
['123a\n', '13aa\n', 'a1\n', '1s2\n', '2\n', '3\n', '3\n', '455\n', '56\n', '6\n', '7\n', '8\n']
123a
is not a valid number,ignoring the same
13aa
is not a valid number,ignoring the same
a1
is not a valid number,ignoring the same
1s2
is not a valid number,ignoring the same
This is a list with numeric values ['2\n', '3\n', '3\n', '455\n', '56\n', '6\n', '7\n', '8\n']
3

3

455

7
```

Note:
My code is working fine and prints the odd numbers however 
I am struggling to check whether list elements are single integer or not.Any pointers will be helpful

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Giving the expected output may be useful, giving your attempts at obtaining it is mandatory.

Comment: A _single odd number_ and _single digit integer_ are two different things. You can check for oddity with `number % 2 != 0` and for single digit integer: `-10 < number < 10` (allowing for a sign).

Comment: Thanks Yes you are right.if int(i) % 2 == 1 and (int(i) <= 9): solves the issue just need to check if I is less than equal to 9

Answer (score 0):

What about using RegEx?

```
test = ['123a', '13aa', 'a1', '1s2', '2', '3', '3', '455', '56', '6', '7', '8']

import re
for s in test:
    m = re.match('[0-9]*', s)
    if m.span()[1] == len(s) and len(s) == 1:
        if int(s) % 2 == 1:
            print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

For checking single integer you can use integer division i.e a // b. If the number is single integer, the division will return 0.

Furthermore you can use filter on the the and select first 5 elements by slicing the list. Example-

```
integer_list = filter(lambda x: x if x % 2 == 1 and x // 10 == 0 else 0, lst1)

integer_list = list(integer_list)[:5]
```